# Covariance and Contravariance: Conflict without a Cause

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, object-oriented

Here is the last paragraph at page 441 of the paper [‘Covariance and Contravariance: Conflict without a Cause’](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=49A40654DC052E5A587315CE378144B6?doi=10.1.1.115.5992&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Giuseppe Castagna:

> How is all this translated into object-oriented type systems? Consider a message $m$ applied (or “sent”) to $n$ objects $e_1$, …, $e_n$ where $e_i$ is an instance of class $C_i$. Suppose we want to consider the classes of only the first $k$ objects in the method selection process. This dispatching scheme can be expressed using the following notation:
>
> $$m(e_1, …, e_k | e_{k+1}, …, e_n).$$
>
> If the type of $m$ is $\{S_i → T_i\}_i$, then the expression above means that we want to select the method whose input type is the $\text{min}_i \{S_i | (C_1 × … × C_k) ≤ S_i\}$ and then to pass it all the $n$ arguments. The type, say $S_j → T_j$, of the selected branch must have the following form:
>
> $$\underbrace{(A_1 × … × A_k)}_{S_j} → \underbrace{(A_{k+1} × … × A_n) → U}_{T_j}$$
>
> where $C_i ≤ A_i$ for $1 ≤ i ≤ k$ and $A_i ≤ C_i$ for $k < i ≤ n$. If we want to override the selected branch by a more precise one, then, as explained above, the new method must covariantly override $A_1, …, A_k$ (to specialize the branch) and contravariantly override $A_{k+1}, …, A_n$ (to have type safety).

I expected $C_i ≤ A_i$ for $1 ≤ i ≤ n$ (instead of $C_i ≤ A_i$ for $1 ≤ i ≤ k$ and $A_i ≤ C_i$ for $k < i ≤ n$), because the call $m(e_1, …, e_n)$ is not type safe if we allow some argument types to be greater than the parameter types of the selected method.

Am I misinterpreting the paragraph or did the author make a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is an error. For an application as in the example the relation must be, of course, the one you wrote, that is,   $C_i≤A_i$ for $1≤i≤n$. The important sentence, however, is the one that follows, namely

> *If we want to override the selected branch by a more precise one, thenthe new method must covariantly override $A_1,…,A_k$ (to specialize the branch) and contravariantly override $A_{k+1},…,A_n$ (to have type safety).*

It is in that case that the relation I (wrongly) wrote for the application must hold. That is, if the overriding method is defined for *parameters* of type $C_1,...,C_n$, then  $C_i≤A_i$ for $1≤i≤k$ and $A_i ≤ C_i$ for $k<i\leq n$. That is just to say that the theory is correct while the explanation is not.

I would strongly suggest abandoning this paper and rather continue with its recent follow-up, since I have reframed the problem of covariance and contravariance in terms of a much more modern type theory and giving practical examples in Perl6: [Covariance and Contravariance: a fresh look at an old issue (a primer in advanced type systems for learning functional programmers)](https://www.irif.fr/%7Egc/papers/covcon-again.pdf) (published in Logical Methods in Computer Science, vol. 16, n. 1, pag. 15:1―15:58, 2020, but the link above gives the latest revised version).

Hopefully, the paper above is much more accessible than my 27-year-old paper, since I wrote it for an audience of undergraduate CS students and all is explained using running code.

P.S. Since I continually revise the paper above, feedback is highly welcome.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the reference to the new article! I have put it on my reading list.